# Apache FTP Server - Connection timeout after 20 seconds of inactivity - Failed to retrieve directory listing

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, ftp, apache-mina, mina

I was looking for a way to create an embedded ftp server. I came across an example ["writing a java ftp server"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970126), which I copied and tested locally and everything seemed fine.

So I went on and deployed the example to an AWS EC2 instance and then tried to access it using Ubuntu and FileZilla as clients but I keep getting the same issue where directories do not get listed. I've even tried opening all ports for the instance and I still get the same thing:

[image: FileZilla Output]

I thought it may have something to do with Active/Passive mode settings so I tried with both on FileZilla but I still get the same issue so I'm all out of ideas. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the FTP server passive mode data connection port range in the server firewall.

By default the Apache MINA FTP server uses any free unprivileged port for the data connection. To avoid opening all ports for the FTP server, restrict range of ports the server can use. See:
https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/configuration_passive_ports.html

To set the range in code, use the [`ListenerFactory.setDataConnectionConfiguration`](https://nightlies.apache.org/mina/ftpserver/1.2.0/apidocs/org/apache/ftpserver/listener/ListenerFactory.html#setDataConnectionConfiguration-org.apache.ftpserver.DataConnectionConfiguration-). You can use the `DefaultDataConnectionConfiguration` as a implementation of the [`DataConnectionConfiguration` interface](https://nightlies.apache.org/mina/ftpserver/1.2.0/apidocs/org/apache/ftpserver/DataConnectionConfiguration.html).

---

See my article on [Network configuration for passive mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand a background.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should try "Passive mode" and "Only use plain FTP (insecure)".

Then, if you are using Windows - try to set "Run the program as an administrator" for the program shortcut or .exe file.
It can be done with right click on program shortcut or .exe file. Then "Properties" - "Compatibility" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Martin Prikryl is correct, however the current version of Apache MINA discourages the construction of a `DefaultDataConnectionConfiguration`.
For those of you who are looking for Java code, please have a look at [Writing a Java FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969097/writing-a-java-startFtpServer-server).
Then the following code fragment can be used to define a range for the passive ports:

```
final var serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
final var factory = new ListenerFactory();
factory.setPort(21); // set the port of the listener (choose your desired port, not 1234)
final var dataConnectionFactory = new DataConnectionConfigurationFactory();
dataConnectionFactory.setPassivePorts("45000-45030"); // or some other range that should be configured in the firewall as well
dataConnectionFactory.createDataConnectionConfiguration();
final var dataConnectionConfig = dataConnectionFactory.createDataConnectionConfiguration();
factory.setDataConnectionConfiguration(dataConnectionConfig);
serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
```